# Call an existing API using Loopback 4

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback4

I have a pre-developed API connected to my backend. I am using loopback 4 as a data provider for my react application.
I want to call the API using Loopback and get the result in my application.
I went through the loopback 4 documentation [calling other API's](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Calling-other-APIs-and-web-services.html#datasource-for-rest-service-without-openapi-specification) but found it a bit confusing.
Data returned by my API is :

`{ "name": "xyz", "place": "xyz", "email": "xyz" }`

I want this data to be returned to my application using Loopback. I do not want to make a direct API call from my React application. I want Loopback to make all the API calls.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A LoopBack 4 application is still a Node.js application. Hence, you can make the request directly in the Controller via the built-in `http` module, or by importing another package (e.g. `request`).

From there, the result can be mutated (if needed) then returned within the Controller.

If API is commonly-used across numerous Controllers, then it is recommended to refactor the requests behind a Service. Services benefit from being bootable at runtime via `this.boot()` and injectable into controllers using `@inject` or `@service`.

Comment: I just want DATA to be returned to my application on hitting the controller URL endpoint. I guess the HTTP module will work well for me.
Can you please add a code snippet of a simple API returning JSON on when that controller URL is being hit from My application. I am totally new to this and have very little knowledge. You can use this API for example: url- 'https://reqres.in/api/users', method: 'GET'. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for the help i have done it using the same process given in the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a datasource via @loopback/service-proxy and use it in the Controller class to call side API.
If u use loopback4: check this link

[strongloop - Calling other APIs](https://lideo.github.io/loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Calling-other-APIs-and-web-services.html)